# How to change Wordpress custom template Archive page title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to change title on Archive page because i use it to list custom article type. In fact, i want to remove "Archive " text at the start of page title.

I use wordpress 5.8 and a custom theme from twenty twenty.

In my header.php file, there is that :

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

But when i write the code below into my `functions.php`, nothing happens.

```
remove_action('wp_head', '_wp_render_title_tag');
```

I have also try to use filter but i don't use it properly because nothing happens too.

How can i do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This one should do the trick :

```
 function change_archive_page_title( $title ) {
        if ( is_category() ) {
            $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
        } 
        return $title;
    }
     
    add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'change_archive_page_title' );
```

Add it to your child theme -> functions.php
Edit: It replace the page title with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Archive Title, there are a few ways.  One is probably using an SEO plugin?  But to do it programmatically, you can use the filter `get_the_archive_title`

Change `your_taxonomy` to the name of the taxonomy you want to modify what is displayed.

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'custom_archive_title', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Change the archive title for a custom taxonomy
 * 
 * @param string $title - The full archive Title
 * @param string $original_title - The name of the archive without prefix.
 * @param string $prefix - Prefix if set - otherwise "Archive"
 * @return mixed
 */
function custom_archive_title( $title, $original_title, $prefix ) {
    // Get the queried object - which would be the WP_Term.
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    // Check if it's your custom taxonomy
    if ( 'your_taxonomy' === $queried_object->taxonomy ) {
        // Remove the prefix.
        $title = $original_title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @HowardE & @DeanTwit but i think my template have a problem beacause when i  write : `echo "i am here"` into the functions, nothing happens.

I have write your code at the end of functions.php.

Is there a manipulation to be performed to run this process ?

Comment: Don't put comments as answers. .. your theme probably overrides the archive.php then.

Comment: I'm so sorry but i dont know the difference beetween answers and comments... In fact, my theme include archive.php that include get_header(). Into my header.php, there is wp_head() so add filter must execute custom function... Very strange ;)